# Django List users in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I get a list of users in a template? I'm a little lost with this one. Can I get the list directly in my template or do I need to add some code elsewhere aswell?

Comment: can share what you tried regarding this?

Comment: you need a view that passes the userlist to your template: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the list of users in the `view` and pass it to the `template` via [`context`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context).